# Visual Studio 2008 Business Intelligence SQL Server, Install C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I have Visual Studio 2008 Business Intelligence version that was installed along with Reporting Services for SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to work with C#, but there are no options to create a C# project. I haven't been able to find any way to install a C# package or something.

Is there a way to add on C# functions, are they already built in but hidden, or should I just download a full version?

Thanks

UPDATE:
So I finally managed to find a download of Visual Studio 2008 Express, and installed the C# version. After installing I launched visual studio and it was the same thing, only the sql server projects came up as templates.

I found a forum that said to go into import and export settings and to reset my settings to general development settings, but I still cannot make a c# project.

UPDATE2:
I'm going to try installing VS 2012 Express to see if that works for me, since its the only download microsoft has that you can easily find now.

UPDATE3:
VS 2012 Express has been working just fine for me, and I still don't have the project templates in VS 2008 though.

Comment: ok this is weird or we're doing something wrong. Just to cover the basics - what types of project do you see after installing VS2008 C# Express? As described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fyc0azh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), there is nothing like a _C# project_, you might need to look for _.Net_ stuff instead.

Comment: When I goto new project, I have the following templates under business intelligence project: analysis services, integration services connections, report server project wizard, report server project, import analysis services, integration services, report model. then under project type other->visual studio solutions I only have a template for a blank solution.

Comment: That seems odd, continuing on the "obvious path" can you double-check whether the VS 2008 Express got installed in the same spot where SQL Server installed the basic VS executables used by BIDS? Perhaps difference in 32 and 64bit version paths?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to install one of the stand-alone editions of Visual Studio.  Business Intelligence Studio, bundled with SQL Server, doesn't allow you to work with C# or other language projects.

Comment: Hey Chris, Mark did mention installing stand-alone VS 2008 Express over the BIDS-related VS shell but to no effect. I'd guess that upon installing Express the otherwise empty VS shell would get enhanced with regular projects. VS 2012 installed separately works fine for him, the question is why 2008 is misbehaving.

Answer (score 3):

*SQL Server 2008 Business Intelligence Development Studio* ("BIDS") is just an add-on over standard Visual Studio (`VS 2008` in this case).

If you hadn't had *Visual Studio* installed before deploying *BIDS*, the most basic *VS* shell was installed along *BIDS* that does not allow you to work with projects other than the *SQL Server* BI family.

For you to work with *.Net* projects, despite being able to edit basic *C#* files already, you will need to reinstall any version of regular *Visual Studio 2008* (e.g. licensed, express). This won't break your *BIDS*.